# how to click submit on achor tag without it refreshing the data on page php, sql and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, real-time

when ever I click send on the anchor tag the whole data on the page coming from the database refreshes. How do I prevent this. I have tried several options online but none works.
my JavaScript code is below. In some way I'm trying to get it like a facebook activity feed where the reatime info is being pushed out and the content that is already there does not disappear and appear on refresh.

```
<script>
    function submitChat() {

        if (form1.msg.value == '') {
            alert('enter your message');
            return;
        }

        $('#imageload').show();
        var msg = form1.msg.value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                $('#imageload').hide();
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?&msg=' + msg, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;    
    }

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#chatlogs').load('reg.php')
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

here is the anchor tag being `echo`d by php

```
<a href=\"#\"onclick=\"submitChat()\" \"onsubmit=return false\" >send</a>
```

Comment: show us the complete anchor tag html please

Comment: I though I submitted it let me try again

Comment: have you checked your console(in firebug or built in), Does it report any error?

Comment: no errors it just refreshes the whole of the data that the database outputs

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitChat()">send</a>
```

Comment: `href = '#'` reloads the page?

Comment: sorry, it's javascript:void(0)

Comment: @littleLouito `With href= "#" you reload the page` is incorrect

Comment: can be `$('#chatlogs').load('reg.php')` the responsible of the reload??  its executing every 2 seconds

Comment: @raidenace you are right. it just goes to the top of the page

Comment: no that don't work either. yes "#" refreshes and takes you the top of the page but so does javascript:void(0).

Comment: But it's not because of the href, but because of submitChat() function

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to

```
currentData = document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('chatlogs').innerHTML = currentData + xmlhttp.responseText;
```